# convert string to mongodb ObjectId in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, object

I am working on client side of MEAN stack for the first time. I want to convert string id from database to mongodb ObjectId so that i can hit api which finds data on the bases of ObjectId.

```
example 
arrayOfId =["5434093d29ca768a74ab3080","5434093d29ca768a74ab3082"]
User.find({"where":{id:{inq:arrayOfId}},function(data));
```

now since the arrayOfId have id in string format i am not able to do query on mongo by find api.
Is there a way to handle this conversion on client side?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(yourId)` but to find using mongoose you don't need to convert *string* to *mongoose ObjectId*. can use like bellow

```
var arrayOfId =["5434093d29ca768a74ab3080","5434093d29ca768a74ab3082"];

User.find({"_id": {$in: arrayOfId }},function(error, data){
  //... 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5434093d29ca768a74ab3080');
```